# How do I pass text format to .cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, special-characters

How do I pass the following textarea without getting a dangerous.Request error?

Using `<% Html.TextArea("Text", Model.fullText, new { @rows="5" }) %>`

```
Happy Holidays!<br><br>In observance of the holiday, we will be closed:
<ul><li>Thursday</li><li>Friday</li><li>Saturday</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `[AllowHtml]` to the model property to disable this validation.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `ValidateRequest = "false"` in your Page directive.

---

```
<%@ Page Trace ="true" ValidateRequest="false" Title="" 
    Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="test.test1"  %>
```